# Permission to queue a TFS Build without a shelveset

Tags: tfsbuild

When queuing a build in TFS 2013, there is an dropdown option named "What do you want to build?" with two options:

- Latest Sources
- Latest Sources with shelveset

As a project collection administrator, both options are enabled for me.  However, for one of our build administrators, the dropdown is disabled.  He is stuck with the default option:

[image: TFS Queue Build Dialog Box]

I've looked at all the build permissions for this user and he has the "allow" permission for all of them, including "Override check-in validation by build."  Does anyone know which specific permission controls this option?  I've searched and although I've found plenty of content describing what the option does, I haven't found which permission controls this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build administrator may use VS 2013. If he does use VS 2013, install this [hotfix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806886/queue-new-build-what-do-you-want-to-build-disabled) that mentioned in this:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806886/queue-new-build-what-do-you-want-to-build-disabled

Comment: Applying VS 2013 Update 5 solved the issue for my build administrator.  Thanks again!